# Local MS SQL 2008 R2 Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server[2] (and [52])

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to a server installed on the same machine that I am using. I installed it using mixed mode. I try to connect using the following command:

`sqlcmd .\SQLEXPRESS -Usa` ...and then I enter my password.

However, I then get the following error:

```
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.
```

I have made sure that Named Pipes and TCP/IP is enabled.

I also get the same error but the error code is [52] if I don't put in the user/pass.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 for my OS, if it matters.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT 1:** Service: "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is started.

Comment: Are You sure, the SQL Server service is started? And also You keep using default name of instance of server?

Comment: Yes, "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" is started.

Comment: Which Authentication use?Windows Authentication Or Sql Server Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to run this in powershell.